# Open the rivers of Heaven?

Tags: meaning, expressions, synonyms

I've heard someone saying "Their task in worship is to open the rivers of Heaven", and I understand that it means something like "Their task is to make worship extremely beautiful", but is there a close synonymical expression or something for "opening the rivers of Heaven"?

Comment: the only thing I found was *Open the rivers of heaven and let flow the Holy Spirit upon the self-will of your Chosen. So that The Holy Spirit guides all thy chosen Children into a willingness...* But you can ask on [Christianity.SE](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I've never heard the expression, but to me it sounds more like the object of the game is to get the goodness (grace, bounty, whatever) to flow from heaven.

Comment: In Greek mythology [*there were **five** rivers in hell*](https://uk.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20070408103355AAVJz38) *- **Acheron**, river of woe; **Lethe**, river of forgetfullness; **Styx**, river that marked the entrance to Death, across which the Dead were ferried by Charon; **Phlegethon**, river of fire; and **Cocytus**, river of wailing.* But unless you count the Milky Way as a "river of heaven", Western traditions don't normally refer to anything like that. Most references are probably from Eastern philosophical contexts (Buddhist texts, etc.). We open the *gates* of heaven.

Comment: it's actually related to Christianity

Answer (score 1):

A synonymous expression could be "The people's heart-cry for revival," but more on that later.

***Water as Metaphor***

The imagery of water is quite prevalent in the Judeo-Christian Scripture, and there are two primary applications of that imagery. The first application concerns the notion of thirst, both physical and spiritual. Just as physical water, H2O, slakes our physical thirst, so also does the water from God slake our spiritual thirst. The second application concerns the notion of God's blessings as a form of spiritual rainfall upon a thirsty world. In both applications, the notions of need and the satisfaction of that need are prominent.

***Slaking Spiritual Thirst***

Spiritual needs may not seem to be as pressing to us as the physical need for water, but they are real, nevertheless. The Scripture takes the basic human need--and the need of all living things--for water and applies it to spiritual matters, matters of the heart and soul. Centuries ago, Israel's king David, cried out to the Lord:

> "O God, thou art my God; early will I seek thee: my soul thirsteth for thee, my flesh longeth for thee in a dry and thirsty land, where no water is" (Psalm 63:1 KJV).

James McGranahan's hymn, *[None But Christ](http://www.hymntime.com/tch/htm/n/o/n/nonebutc.htm)*, captures the essence of David's heart-cry to God:

> I sighed for rest and happiness,
> I yearned for them, not Thee;
> But, while I passed my Savior by,
> His love laid hold on me.
>
> I tried the broken cisterns, Lord,
> But, ah, the waters failed;
> Even as I stooped to drink they fled,
> And mocked me as I wailed.
>
> The pleasures lost I sadly mourned,
> But never wept for Thee,
> Till grace the sightless eyes received,
> Thy loveliness to see.

You can tell from the hymn excerpts, above, that the theme of the Blaise Pascal quotation which contains the phrase "God-shaped vacuum" is rife in Christian hymnody. The Christian notion that the things of this world can never truly fill that vacuum can be traced to Christ himself, who said,

> "'He who believes in Me, as the Scripture said, *From his innermost being will flow rivers of living water'*" (John 7:38 NAS).

In the account of "Jesus and the Woman at the Well" (see the Gospel of John, chapter 4), Jesus "breaks the ice," so to speak, when he asks the woman for a drink of water. Later in the conversation when *he* offers water to *her*, he is referring to the only water that truly satisfies the human heart.

> "'If you knew the gift of God, and who it is who says to you, 'Give me a drink,' you would have asked him, and he would have given you living water. . . . Everyone who drinks of this [well] water will thirst again; but whoever drinks of the water that I will give him shall never thirst, but the water that I will give him will become in him a well of water springing up to eternal life'" (excerpts from verses 10, 13, and 14).

The metaphorical imagery in the above quotation is obvious, to be sure. There is another aspect of this water metaphor, however.

***Rivers of Blessing On Society at Large***

The refrain from Daniel W. Whittle's hymn, *Showers of Blessing*, says,

> Showers of blessing,
> Showers of blessing we need:
> Mercy-drops round us are falling,
> But for the showers we plead.

The imagery here causes us to associate God's blessing of people with his provision of water to the spiritually "dry and thirsty land" in which they live. In other words, what we lack, whether it be in a community, a city, a state, a country, or even in the entire world, God can abundantly supply with his "rivers of living water." To change the metaphor, these "showers of blessing" can be seen most clearly during a time of spiritual revival.

During the [Third Great Awakening](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Awakening) in the United States (ca. 1850s - 1950s), for example, thanks to the preaching of men such as Dwight L. Moody, not only did church enrollments spike, but various societal reforms followed in the wake of spiritual revival; for example, the founding of the YMCA and its Christian Commission ([the USSC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_Christian_Commission)),

> "an organization that furnished supplies, medical services, and religious literature to Union troops during the American Civil War. It combined religious support with social services and recreational activities. It supplied Protestant chaplains and social workers and collaborated with the U.S. Sanitary Commission in providing medical services";

the United States Sanitary Commission, "a private relief agency created by federal legislation on June 18, 1861, to support sick and wounded soldiers of the U.S. Army during the American Civil War"; and numerous Freedmen's Societies, such as the FAS:

> "[The Freedmen’s Aid Society](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freedmen%27s_Aid_Society) [which] was founded in 1861 during the American Civil War by the American Missionary Association (AMA), a group supported chiefly by the Congregational, Presbyterian and Methodist churches in the North. It organized a supply of teachers from the North and provided housing for them, to set up and teach in schools in the South for freedmen and their children. The AMA founded a total of more than 500 schools and colleges for freedmen in the South after the war, so that freedmen could be educated as teachers, nurses and other professionals."

***Conclusion***

If I am not mistaken, then, your quotation, "Their task in worship is to open the rivers of Heaven," has a two-fold application. First, it represents the pleading of God's people to satisfy them with his fullness and presence, so that the "things of earth . . . grow strangely dim," as one [hymn writer](http://cyberhymnal.org/htm/t/u/turnyour.htm) put it, and second, the pleading of God's people to pour out on their neighborhoods, communities, cities, and countries the healing flow of his limitless supply of rivers of water which alone can truly satisfy the deepest needs of the human heart.

Comment: nice answer... should I then understand that there is no synonymical expression for "opening the rivers of Heaven"?

Comment: @SorinAdrianCarbunaru: Perhaps "A heart-cry for revival"? This is the second sense, in my answer above. When the church, writ large, is revived, God pours out rivers of living water on a community, town, city, state, and/or country. The effects of that consequent revival could include: dramatic increase in church attendance and membership and widespread confession and repentance among churchgoers; decrease in crime--drugs, theft, violence, and the emptying of prisons; decrease in alcohol consumption; bars close; fractured families are restored; and charitable non-profit entities proliferate.

Comment: @AndrewLeach: Thanks for the edit, Andrew. I learn something every day! Don

Comment: Chapter 22 of the book of Revelation specifically mentions a "River of Life." https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Revelation+22&version=ESV

Comment: @wordsmythe: Good point. If my answer weren't as wordy as it already is, I'd edit it to include the words you quote from Revelation 22. Don